# Split array base on result of checking element

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP as below:

`

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some text
            [1] => 6230.C3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some text
            [1] => 6230.C3
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some text
            [1] => 
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some text
            [1] => 
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some text
            [1] => 
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some text
            [1] => 
        )
    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some text
            [1] => 
        )
)
```

`

Array[2] and Array[6] are empty arrays. Please help me split my array to three arrays array1, array2, array3 as below (split at position of Array[2] and Array[6]).

```
array1 = [ Array[0], Array[1] ]
array2 = [ Array[3], Array[4], Array[5] ]
Aarray3 = [ Array[7], Array[8] ]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little more flexible than your original question because it is not limited to exactly 3 arrays as separate variables.  The result of the following would be an multidimensional array, split in the way that you want but for an unlimited number of splits.  I can rework it if necessary to fit exactly 3 variables if that is really what your input will always be.

```
<?php
$final = array();
$counter = 0;
$outerEmpty = false;
foreach($originalArray as $outer) {
    $innerEmpty = true;
    foreach($outer as $inner) {
        if (!empty($inner)) {
            $innerEmpty = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$innerEmpty)
        $final[$counter][] = $outer;
    else
        $counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, **@mtr.web**. Your code so beautyful and help me a lot.